# C++ Problem with referencing a bool from an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, menu, boolean, directx

I'm working on a new directX menu for a game since my previous menu was getting really outdated and was coded poorly.

I'm currently doing a lot of stuff in arrays and loops, yet i'm having one problem. When i load up an Array with some booleans, and I go through the Array and pass the booleans to a function, it won't work.

When pressing a button on the menu, the boolean has to be either enabled or disabled. When I try to do it directly without an Array, it works. The boolean gets enabled and disabled when i want it to.

I currently don't know why the boolean wouldn't be recognized when i simply add it in a loop.

Loop Code:

```
    const char* ButtonArray[] = { "Button1", "Button2", "Button3" };
bool varsArray[] = { bool1, bool2, bool3};

int iWrapperHeight = (ARRAYSIZE(ButtonArray) + 1) * iItemHeight;
defWrapperHeight = iWrapperHeight;

Wrapper* wrapper1 = new Wrapper(0, iBodyX, iBodyY, iTabWidth, iWrapperHeight, "Wrapper");
wrapper1->Draw();

CreateOption* option = new CreateOption(0, iBodyX, iBodyY += (iItemHeight * 0.5), iW, iH);
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(ButtonArray); i++) {
    option->ToggleButton(iItemHeight, ButtonArray[i], varsArray[i]);
}
```

This is where i draw a wrapper, draw buttons etc...

Now, if i were to change the

```
option->ToggleButton(iItemHeight, ButtonArray[i], varsArray[i]);
```

to

```
option->ToggleButton(iItemHeight, ButtonArray[i], bool1);
```

The code works. This is obviously not what i want since 3 buttons will affect the same boolean.
My ToggleButton function looks like this.

```
void ToggleButton(int iYAdder, const char* szTitle, bool& bVar)
```

and if the mouse is at the correct spot & the mouse clicked: bVar = !bVar

So yeah, i've been looking around if i perhaps screwed up the working of the Array, not sure.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Can you please expand and elaborate on the "it won't work" part? How doesn't it work? How do you notice? Where do you notice?

Comment: Appologies. When i log the boolean its value, it says the value is 1. Which doesnt make sense since i'm rendering the button color to be green once the value has hit 1. otherwise stay grey when the value is at 0. In my example where i say that it works but it's not what i'm trying to accomplish. The button turns green when i hit the button. The problem is all 3 buttons light up since im running the code 3 times with the same boolean. I'm guessing my for loop is incorrect.

Comment: Note that, with `option->ToggleButton(..., varsArray[i]);` call, when the function performs its `bVar = !bVar` flip, it's flipping the value of an element of `varsArray`. It is **not** flipping the value of `boolX` variable from which that element was originally initialized. There's no magic connection between the two. It seems you are looking at `boolX` variables in the debugger and expecting them to change - that won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ***guessing*** here since you don't show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't know how you check or use the values in the array.

You define and initialize the `bool` array as

```
bool varsArray[] = { bool1, bool2, bool3};
```

That means you *copy* the original values from `bool1` through `bool3`. And you pass these new values to the `ToggleButton` function, which means the references in that function will be references to the array elements.

My *guess* is that you don't check the array, but rather the distinct variables `bool1` through `bool3`, which of course won't change since you don't pass references to those variables.

Either you need to refactor your code to check the values of `varsArray[0]` through `varsArray[2]`, or create an array of references (or rather, since it's not possible to create an array of references directly, using [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) as created by [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)).